# Automatically Format an OS X/macOS XML Property List's Indentation and Self-Closing Tag Styles

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, plist, xmllint

I'd like to automatically format one or more OS X/macOS XML property list files to use formatting like one would get by running '`xmllint --format`' on them, except that:

- I want keys' values to similarly be indented by one level (two spaces) underneath their parent keys.
- I *don't* want keys with '`<data>`' values to have those get split across multiple lines.

I also want all self-closing tags to have spaces just before their closing slashes.  What XSLT (edit:  or other) transformation would I use to achieve this?

---

As requested, here is a minimal working example (adapted slightly from [this piece of Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/Saving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001175-CJBEHAAG):)

- Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Year Of Birth</key>
    <integer>1965</integer>
    <key>Pets&apos; Names</key>
    <array/>
    <key>Picture</key>
    <data>
        PEKBpYGlmYFCPA==
    </data>
    <key>City of Birth</key>
    <string>Springfield</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>John Doe</string>
    <key>Kids&apos; Names</key>
    <array>
        <string>John</string>
        <string>Kyra</string>
    </array>
    <key>Pangram</key>
    <data>
    VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4gIA
    </data>
    <key>FollowingKeyDataLengthIsInsane</key>
    <true/>
    <key>&apos;Lorem Ipsum&apos; Sample Text</key>
    <data>
    TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdCwg
    c2VkIGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWdu
    YSBhbGlxdWEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQgbWluaW0gdmVuaWFtLCBxdWlzIG5vc3RydWQgZXhlcmNpdGF0
    aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZXggZWEgY29tbW9kbyBjb25zZXF1
    YXQuIER1aXMgYXV0ZSBpcnVyZSBkb2xvciBpbiByZXByZWhlbmRlcml0IGluIHZvbHVwdGF0ZSB2
    ZWxpdCBlc3NlIGNpbGx1bSBkb2xvcmUgZXUgZnVnaWF0IG51bGxhIHBhcmlhdHVyLiBFeGNlcHRl
    dXIgc2ludCBvY2NhZWNhdCBjdXBpZGF0YXQgbm9uIHByb2lkZW50LCBzdW50IGluIGN1bHBhIHF1
    aSBvZmZpY2lhIGRlc2VydW50IG1vbGxpdCBhbmltIGlkIGVzdCBsYWJvcnVtLgpDdXJhYml0dXIg
    cHJldGl1bSB0aW5jaWR1bnQgbGFjdXMuIE51bGxhIGdyYXZpZGEgb3JjaSBhIG9kaW8uIE51bGxh
    bSB2YXJpdXMsIHR1cnBpcyBldCBjb21tb2RvIHBoYXJldHJhLCBlc3QgZXJvcyBiaWJlbmR1bSBl
    bGl0LCBuZWMgbHVjdHVzIG1hZ25hIGZlbGlzIHNvbGxpY2l0dWRpbiBtYXVyaXMuIEludGVnZXIg
    aW4gbWF1cmlzIGV1IG5pYmggZXVpc21vZCBncmF2aWRhLiBEdWlzIGFjIHRlbGx1cyBldCByaXN1
    cyB2dWxwdXRhdGUgdmVoaWN1bGEuIERvbmVjIGxvYm9ydGlzIHJpc3VzIGEgZWxpdC4gRXRpYW0g
    dGVtcG9yLiBVdCB1bGxhbWNvcnBlciwgbGlndWxhIGV1IHRlbXBvciBjb25ndWUsIGVyb3MgZXN0
    IGV1aXNtb2QgdHVycGlzLCBpZCB0aW5jaWR1bnQgc2FwaWVuIHJpc3VzIGEgcXVhbS4gTWFlY2Vu
    YXMgZmVybWVudHVtIGNvbnNlcXVhdCBtaS4gRG9uZWMgZmVybWVudHVtLiBQZWxsZW50ZXNxdWUg
    bWFsZXN1YWRhIG51bGxhIGEgbWkuIER1aXMgc2FwaWVuIHNlbSwgYWxpcXVldCBuZWMsIGNvbW1v
    ZG8gZWdldCwgY29uc2VxdWF0IHF1aXMsIG5lcXVlLiBBbGlxdWFtIGZhdWNpYnVzLCBlbGl0IHV0
    IGRpY3R1bSBhbGlxdWV0LCBmZWxpcyBuaXNsIGFkaXBpc2Npbmcgc2FwaWVuLCBzZWQgbWFsZXN1
    YWRhIGRpYW0gbGFjdXMgZWdldCBlcmF0LiBDcmFzIG1vbGxpcyBzY2VsZXJpc3F1ZSBudW5jLiBO
    dWxsYW0gYXJjdS4gQWxpcXVhbSBjb25zZXF1YXQuIEN1cmFiaXR1ciBhdWd1ZSBsb3JlbSwgZGFw
    aWJ1cyBxdWlzLCBsYW9yZWV0IGV0LCBwcmV0aXVtIGFjLCBuaXNpLiBBZW5lYW4gbWFnbmEgbmlz
    bCwgbW9sbGlzIHF1aXMsIG1vbGVzdGllIGV1LCBmZXVnaWF0IGluLCBvcmNpLiBJbiBoYWMgaGFi
    aXRhc3NlIHBsYXRlYSBkaWN0dW1zdC4=
    </data>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- (Edit:  What `xmllint` outputs, given this example in a file named '`sample.plist`:'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Year Of Birth</key>
    <integer>1965</integer>
    <key>Pets' Names</key>
    <array/>
    <key>Picture</key>
    <data>
        PEKBpYGlmYFCPA==
    </data>
    <key>City of Birth</key>
    <string>Springfield</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>John Doe</string>
    <key>Kids' Names</key>
    <array>
      <string>John</string>
      <string>Kyra</string>
    </array>
    <key>Pangram</key>
    <data>
    VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4gIA
    </data>
    <key>FollowingKeyDataLengthIsInsane</key>
    <true/>
    <key>'Lorem Ipsum' Sample Text</key>
    <data>
    TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdCwg
    c2VkIGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWdu
    YSBhbGlxdWEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQgbWluaW0gdmVuaWFtLCBxdWlzIG5vc3RydWQgZXhlcmNpdGF0
    aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZXggZWEgY29tbW9kbyBjb25zZXF1
    YXQuIER1aXMgYXV0ZSBpcnVyZSBkb2xvciBpbiByZXByZWhlbmRlcml0IGluIHZvbHVwdGF0ZSB2
    ZWxpdCBlc3NlIGNpbGx1bSBkb2xvcmUgZXUgZnVnaWF0IG51bGxhIHBhcmlhdHVyLiBFeGNlcHRl
    dXIgc2ludCBvY2NhZWNhdCBjdXBpZGF0YXQgbm9uIHByb2lkZW50LCBzdW50IGluIGN1bHBhIHF1
    aSBvZmZpY2lhIGRlc2VydW50IG1vbGxpdCBhbmltIGlkIGVzdCBsYWJvcnVtLgpDdXJhYml0dXIg
    cHJldGl1bSB0aW5jaWR1bnQgbGFjdXMuIE51bGxhIGdyYXZpZGEgb3JjaSBhIG9kaW8uIE51bGxh
    bSB2YXJpdXMsIHR1cnBpcyBldCBjb21tb2RvIHBoYXJldHJhLCBlc3QgZXJvcyBiaWJlbmR1bSBl
    bGl0LCBuZWMgbHVjdHVzIG1hZ25hIGZlbGlzIHNvbGxpY2l0dWRpbiBtYXVyaXMuIEludGVnZXIg
    aW4gbWF1cmlzIGV1IG5pYmggZXVpc21vZCBncmF2aWRhLiBEdWlzIGFjIHRlbGx1cyBldCByaXN1
    cyB2dWxwdXRhdGUgdmVoaWN1bGEuIERvbmVjIGxvYm9ydGlzIHJpc3VzIGEgZWxpdC4gRXRpYW0g
    dGVtcG9yLiBVdCB1bGxhbWNvcnBlciwgbGlndWxhIGV1IHRlbXBvciBjb25ndWUsIGVyb3MgZXN0
    IGV1aXNtb2QgdHVycGlzLCBpZCB0aW5jaWR1bnQgc2FwaWVuIHJpc3VzIGEgcXVhbS4gTWFlY2Vu
    YXMgZmVybWVudHVtIGNvbnNlcXVhdCBtaS4gRG9uZWMgZmVybWVudHVtLiBQZWxsZW50ZXNxdWUg
    bWFsZXN1YWRhIG51bGxhIGEgbWkuIER1aXMgc2FwaWVuIHNlbSwgYWxpcXVldCBuZWMsIGNvbW1v
    ZG8gZWdldCwgY29uc2VxdWF0IHF1aXMsIG5lcXVlLiBBbGlxdWFtIGZhdWNpYnVzLCBlbGl0IHV0
    IGRpY3R1bSBhbGlxdWV0LCBmZWxpcyBuaXNsIGFkaXBpc2Npbmcgc2FwaWVuLCBzZWQgbWFsZXN1
    YWRhIGRpYW0gbGFjdXMgZWdldCBlcmF0LiBDcmFzIG1vbGxpcyBzY2VsZXJpc3F1ZSBudW5jLiBO
    dWxsYW0gYXJjdS4gQWxpcXVhbSBjb25zZXF1YXQuIEN1cmFiaXR1ciBhdWd1ZSBsb3JlbSwgZGFw
    aWJ1cyBxdWlzLCBsYW9yZWV0IGV0LCBwcmV0aXVtIGFjLCBuaXNpLiBBZW5lYW4gbWFnbmEgbmlz
    bCwgbW9sbGlzIHF1aXMsIG1vbGVzdGllIGV1LCBmZXVnaWF0IGluLCBvcmNpLiBJbiBoYWMgaGFi
    aXRhc3NlIHBsYXRlYSBkaWN0dW1zdC4=
    </data>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

This isn't what I want, but I've added it for completeness's sake.)

- After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Year Of Birth</key>
    <integer>1965</integer>
  <key>Pets&apos; Names</key>
    <array />
  <key>Picture</key>
    <data>
      PEKBpYGlmYFCPA==
    </data>
  <key>City of Birth</key>
    <string>Springfield</string>
  <key>Name</key>
    <string>John Doe</string>
  <key>Kids&apos; Names</key>
    <array>
      <string>John</string>
      <string>Kyra</string>
    </array>
  <key>Pangram</key>
    <data>
      VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4gIA
    </data>
  <key>FollowingKeyDataLengthIsInsane</key>
    <true />
  <key>&apos;Lorem Ipsum&apos; Sample Text</key>
    <data>
      TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdCwg
      c2VkIGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWdu
      YSBhbGlxdWEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQgbWluaW0gdmVuaWFtLCBxdWlzIG5vc3RydWQgZXhlcmNpdGF0
      aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZXggZWEgY29tbW9kbyBjb25zZXF1
      YXQuIER1aXMgYXV0ZSBpcnVyZSBkb2xvciBpbiByZXByZWhlbmRlcml0IGluIHZvbHVwdGF0ZSB2
      ZWxpdCBlc3NlIGNpbGx1bSBkb2xvcmUgZXUgZnVnaWF0IG51bGxhIHBhcmlhdHVyLiBFeGNlcHRl
      dXIgc2ludCBvY2NhZWNhdCBjdXBpZGF0YXQgbm9uIHByb2lkZW50LCBzdW50IGluIGN1bHBhIHF1
      aSBvZmZpY2lhIGRlc2VydW50IG1vbGxpdCBhbmltIGlkIGVzdCBsYWJvcnVtLgpDdXJhYml0dXIg
      cHJldGl1bSB0aW5jaWR1bnQgbGFjdXMuIE51bGxhIGdyYXZpZGEgb3JjaSBhIG9kaW8uIE51bGxh
      bSB2YXJpdXMsIHR1cnBpcyBldCBjb21tb2RvIHBoYXJldHJhLCBlc3QgZXJvcyBiaWJlbmR1bSBl
      bGl0LCBuZWMgbHVjdHVzIG1hZ25hIGZlbGlzIHNvbGxpY2l0dWRpbiBtYXVyaXMuIEludGVnZXIg
      aW4gbWF1cmlzIGV1IG5pYmggZXVpc21vZCBncmF2aWRhLiBEdWlzIGFjIHRlbGx1cyBldCByaXN1
      cyB2dWxwdXRhdGUgdmVoaWN1bGEuIERvbmVjIGxvYm9ydGlzIHJpc3VzIGEgZWxpdC4gRXRpYW0g
      dGVtcG9yLiBVdCB1bGxhbWNvcnBlciwgbGlndWxhIGV1IHRlbXBvciBjb25ndWUsIGVyb3MgZXN0
      IGV1aXNtb2QgdHVycGlzLCBpZCB0aW5jaWR1bnQgc2FwaWVuIHJpc3VzIGEgcXVhbS4gTWFlY2Vu
      YXMgZmVybWVudHVtIGNvbnNlcXVhdCBtaS4gRG9uZWMgZmVybWVudHVtLiBQZWxsZW50ZXNxdWUg
      bWFsZXN1YWRhIG51bGxhIGEgbWkuIER1aXMgc2FwaWVuIHNlbSwgYWxpcXVldCBuZWMsIGNvbW1v
      ZG8gZWdldCwgY29uc2VxdWF0IHF1aXMsIG5lcXVlLiBBbGlxdWFtIGZhdWNpYnVzLCBlbGl0IHV0
      IGRpY3R1bSBhbGlxdWV0LCBmZWxpcyBuaXNsIGFkaXBpc2Npbmcgc2FwaWVuLCBzZWQgbWFsZXN1
      YWRhIGRpYW0gbGFjdXMgZWdldCBlcmF0LiBDcmFzIG1vbGxpcyBzY2VsZXJpc3F1ZSBudW5jLiBO
      dWxsYW0gYXJjdS4gQWxpcXVhbSBjb25zZXF1YXQuIEN1cmFiaXR1ciBhdWd1ZSBsb3JlbSwgZGFw
      aWJ1cyBxdWlzLCBsYW9yZWV0IGV0LCBwcmV0aXVtIGFjLCBuaXNpLiBBZW5lYW4gbWFnbmEgbmlz
      bCwgbW9sbGlzIHF1aXMsIG1vbGVzdGllIGV1LCBmZXVnaWF0IGluLCBvcmNpLiBJbiBoYWMgaGFi
      aXRhc3NlIHBsYXRlYSBkaWN0dW1zdC4=
    </data>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Please add an example of input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: I've added one now.

Comment: I am afraid none of this is feasible or practical. **1.** Keys are not parents of their values, they are siblings. Even if you manage to indent a value relative to its key, you will eliminate the difference in indentation between the value and its own children. Unless you do your own indentation, which is possible, but a lot of work. **2.** XSLT does not split data across multiple lines (unless you explicitly instruct it so and build the mechanism for it); if you don't want lines to wrap, adjust your viewing application's preferences.

Comment: **3.** I don't know of a way to add a space to an element name (which is what your last request comes down to). An element name cannot contain the space character. If you try to add it, you will either get an error, or the processor will ignore it. You might be able to achieve this through adjusting the XSLT processor's settings, but not through the stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah, the amount of work involved in doing my own indentation is exactly what I want to avoid here.  When you say, "XSLT does not split data across multiple lines," do you mean that with respect to the full '`data`' tags involved here, or just their contents?  If the latter, those, as evident in my example, are already split across multiple lines, so any processing done naturally wouldn't need to change that.  `xmllint`, at least, seems to handle the former case just fine; I'll add an example of what it outputs to my question, even though that's not what I want here.

Comment: Finally, maybe a non-XSLT tool might be what I need to achieve what I want here…?

Comment: I've added example '`xmllint --format`' output now.

Comment: (On another note, I've just noticed an odd inconsistency in `xmllint` output behavior between my example and one of the files I'm really trying to format when it comes to '`<data>`' elements:  on ones that aren't nested too deeply (and at leas tin my example,) it doesn't change the indentation of said '`<data>`' elements' contents with respect to their enclosing tags; ones that have deeper nesting (and in this other file,) it handles the leading tag properly, but leaves the element's contents' indentation unchanged and indents the closing tag to match its element's contents' indentation.)

Comment: My comments are limited to XSLT. I don't know about other tools. Re splitting data, I mean that text nodes are passed unchanged by default. There are various options regarding white space between elements, that I will not enumerate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, here's how you can indent the output yourself:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="indent-unit" select="'&#9;'"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="indent" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, $indent-unit)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($indent, 1, string-length($indent) - string-length($indent-unit))"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::key]]">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent, $indent-unit)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, $indent-unit, $indent-unit)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($indent, 1, string-length($indent) - string-length($indent-unit))"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4J6

Comment: Thank you very much!  That'll be a _lot_ easier than inserting all that indentation by hand.

Comment: Hmm, I think my local versions of '`xmllint`' and '`xsltproc`' are buggy.  I'll just use that web link for now, since that works, and deal with local package management later…

Comment: It works fine for me with `xsltproc`, with one exception: there is an empty line between the XML declaration and the root element. This could be eliminated with some extra work (which I am not going to do).

Comment: What version do you have?  '`xsltproc --version`' gives me:  

```
Using libxml 20902, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20902, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
libxslt 10128 was compiled against libxml 20902
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20902
```

This is probably relatively old, I suspect.

Comment: The version included with macOS 10.13.6: "Using libxml 20904, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20904, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817
libxslt 10129 was compiled against libxml 20904
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20904"

Comment: OK, that's not as much of a version difference as one might suspect.  Something else must be weird in my environment, but I'm not troubleshooting it now; I have bigger fish to fry…

Comment: This actually doesn't handle '`<data>`' elements spread out over multiple lines.  Then again, you already said it wouldn't.

Comment: Actually, when you edit and save a property list in Xcode, it puts '`<data>`' tags all on one line, so this is just fine.

Comment: I do have _one_ more question, though…:  are those values `select`ed for this style sheet's `param`s default ones, or are they expressions telling `xsltproc` how to parse the input parameters?  If the latter, what would the expected argument values for those parameters be?  '`--stringparam indent "  " --stringparam indent-unit "  "`' produces the results I want, but I'm not sure if that's right…

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. `indent-unit` in my stylesheet is a global parameter. It has a default value of horizontal tab. You can override that value by calling the transformation with your own parameter (as you seem to be doing). There are no other global parameters.

Comment: (_Stares at the code a bit more, then facepalms._)  _O_-kay, I _think_ I get it now:  '`$indent`' is a local control variable used passed to the '`select`' statements for it to use when determining _what lines_ to indent, namely by looking for that character and then adding '`$indent-unit`' after it.  The default of '`"'&#10;'"`' (ASCII line feed) is fine, as that's what I'd want:  to modify the indentation of every new line.  Since '`$indent`' is a _local_ parameter, any global argument of the same parameter name you pass in will remain at the global scope, and thus be shadowed, correct?

Comment: If you pass a parameter named `indent` it will be ignored, because there is no global parameter with that name. Also, `indent` is NOT used to determine *what* lines to indent. It is used to determine the indent *amount* - IOW, the string to output before the start-tag of the current element. Since the processing recurses down the tree, and every generation adds one indent-unit to the indent it passes down to its children, you get  a property indented tree (with the exception of elements that follow a `key`, that get an extra unit).